# Have I lost Swish?

Tags: song-of-the-deep

I was introduced to [a new friend, Swish](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpaxK4Vou_E) who found a torpedo for me. I blew open the right-hand door and Swish went through, but I didn't follow. I left that screen to go and try break another door. Now I've come back and gone through the right-hand door, but I can't find Swish. Have I lost them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is exactly what is meant to happen. Without giving too much away, you will see more of Swish later.